# How to display œ words when I searching?

Tags: ios7

Now I'm currently working on ingredients App.

Here I face some special characters issue. (ie.,) I have listed some recipe list from Web service URL.

In Web service URL, some of the recipes are listed with special characters like as below,

Bœuf bourguignon, Bœuf ficelle and Boeuf laqué...etc.

So I have implement the searching functionality in local.

At that time I type "Boe" in search bar,  It was shown only the Boeuf laqué, not the below recipes,

Bœuf bourguignon, Bœuf ficelle.

How to display the above recipes When I type "Boe" in search bar.

If you know the solutions, give suggestion to me.

I will really appreciate to you.

Comment: Any body know the solution for the above one ?

Comment: It's up to you to program it. You will have the same problem with Oeuf Soeur Coeur etc ... So in your code add that when oe is present you also have to search for œ

Comment: Show us the code you have so far for the search functionnality.